# How to make the scale to round to the nearest multiple of #?

Tags: javascript, axis, d3.js, rounding

```
x.scale = d3.time.scale().domain(x.extent).range([0, dimensions.graph.width]);
```

This code uses `x.extent` (`[Wed Aug 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST), Tue Aug 07 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)]`) and graph width (1000) to generate `x` value scale. However, I need this value to be rounded to the nearest multiple of 25 (`Math.round(x/25)*25`).

By doing this I want to achieve exact width ticks that are now defined as:

```
x.axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
    .tickSize(10, 5, 0)
    .scale(x.scale);
```

How to extend `x.scale` to round to the nearest multiple of 25?

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer is `interpolateRound`, from the docs

> Returns an interpolator between the two numbers a and b; the interpolator is similar to `interpolateNumber`, except it will round the resulting value to the nearest integer.

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, width])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateRound); // <-- round interpolation
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for the [nice](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_nice) function?

```
x.scale = d3.time.scale().domain(x.extent)
            .range([0, dimensions.graph.width]).nice();
```

Comment: correct link: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous_nice

Answer (score 1):

perhaps I am misunderstanding, but couldn't you just transform the result as you suggested after applying the scale function? ie:

```
function roundScale(origVal) { return Math.round(x.scale(origVal)/25) * 25;}
```

then use that value to set attributes:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return roundScale(d.value); }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want, with one little problem – I need it to maintain its `d3.time.scale()` properties, because otherwise `d3.svg.axis` will not match the `x.scale`.